# Trigger executing a custom shell script inside a container to run migrations and db:seed after docker build is complete from docker-compose.yml

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I have created my docker-compose.yml file to make containers for a Laravel project and I created a separate project_setup.sh script to do composer install,npm install and DB migration. is there a way to automate this like once both containers up run the sh script from inside apache server container where files are located without manually log in to the container and run the file.

my current docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '3.5'

services:
    laravel-app:
        build:
          context: '.'
        container_name: my-app
        volumes:
          - ./:/var/www/html
          - ./docker_configs/custom.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
          - ./docker_configs/laravel-worker.conf:/etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-worker.conf
          - ./docker_configs/docker_cron:/etc/cron.d/docker_cron
        working_dir: /var/www/html
        ports:
          - 8080:80
        networks:
          backend:
            aliases:
              - app

    mariadb:
        image: mariadb:10.2
        container_name: my-db
        volumes:
          - ./run/var:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
           - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
           - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
           - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
           - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
        ports:
          - 3309:3306
        networks:
          backend:
            aliases:
              - db

networks:
  backend:
    name: backend-network
```

I'm just using latest MariaDB image with database settings my docker file in case

```
FROM php:7.3.12-apache-stretch

RUN apt-get autoclean

RUN apt-get update

# 1. development packages
RUN apt-get install -y \
    apt-utils \
    build-essential \
    debconf-utils \
    debconf \
    default-mysql-client \
    locales \
    git \
    memcached \
    zip \
    sudo \
    wget \
    gnupg \
    unzip \
    nano \
    libxml2-dev \
    libldb-dev \
    libldap2-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libbz2-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    openssh-client \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libreadline-dev \
    libmagickwand-dev \
    libmemcached-dev \
    libmagickcore-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    cron \
    supervisor

RUN \
  echo "deb http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
  echo "deb-src http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
  echo "deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
  echo "deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
  apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qqy upgrade && apt-get -q autoclean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# 2. apache configs + document root
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

# 3. mod_rewrite for URL rewrite and mod_headers for .htaccess extra headers like Access-Control-Allow-Origin-
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

# 4. start with base php config, then add extensions
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    bcmath \
    bz2 \   
    dom \
    gd \
    json \
    ldap \
    mbstring \
    pgsql \
    mysqli \    
    intl \
    iconv \    
    opcache \
    calendar \
    pdo_mysql \
    pdo_pgsql \
    xml

RUN docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl && \
    docker-php-ext-install imap

RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip && \
    docker-php-ext-install zip

#add unsupported php files via pecl
RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug && \
    pecl install mcrypt && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt && \
    pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini && \
    pecl install imagick && docker-php-ext-enable imagick   


RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/memcached
WORKDIR /usr/src/php/ext/memcached
RUN wget https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/archive/v3.1.3.zip; unzip /usr/src/php/ext/memcached/v3.1.3.zip
RUN mv /usr/src/php/ext/memcached/php-memcached-3.1.3/* /usr/src/php/ext/memcached/

RUN docker-php-ext-configure memcached && docker-php-ext-install memcached

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/memcache
WORKDIR /usr/src/php/ext/memcache
RUN wget https://github.com/websupport-sk/pecl-memcache/archive/4.0.4.zip; unzip /usr/src/php/ext/memcache/4.0.4.zip
RUN mv /usr/src/php/ext/memcache/pecl-memcache-4.0.4/* /usr/src/php/ext/memcache/

RUN docker-php-ext-install memcache && docker-php-ext-configure memcache

# 6. Configure needed apache modules and disable default site
RUN a2dismod   mpm_event  cgi # mpm_worker enabled.
RUN a2enmod     \
  access_compat     \
  actions       \
  alias         \
  auth_basic        \
  authn_core        \
  authn_file        \
  authz_core        \
  authz_groupfile   \
  authz_host        \
  authz_user        \
  autoindex     \
  dir           \
  env           \
  expires       \
  filter        \
  headers       \
  mime          \
  negotiation       \
  mpm_prefork       \
  reqtimeout        \
  rewrite       \
  setenvif      \
  status        \
  ssl

# 7. composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Install Node.js
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN node -v
RUN npm -v
```

maybe my approach wrong.. I appreciate any support.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Comment: @soju I need to automate this right after docker build and containers are up without manually exec to the laravel-app container. is there any other way I've missed? because DB container should be up and running to run DB migrations from laravel-app container.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on

Comment: Your laravel container should `depends_on` mariadb. Then you could exec your script after your stack is up.

Comment: yes trying adding so thanks for pointing out.. will try and update here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

i created the files required for building the docker container.Hope it'll be usefull to anyone else.

https://github.com/Madu-rosh/laravel-docker-setup